# What is the 'icon' argument for ipywidgets.Button?

Tags: documentation, ipywidgets

I am trying to understand how to display buttons in an jupyter notebook, but the [documentation](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20List.html#Button) is a bis sparse on this item.

It is mentioned there is an argument 'icon'. But what does it mean? What values can be used? Is there some documentation hidden somewhere else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can specify an icon from the Font Awesome 4.7 catalog, by prefacing with `fa-`.

https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icons/

```py
import ipywidgets as ipyw

ipyw.Button(
    description = 'Button',
    icon = 'fa-bullhorn',
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the documentation indicates that icon is the `FontAwesome names without the 'fa-' prefixname`. [see doc here](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20List.html#Button):

```py
button = widgets.Button(
    description='Click me',
    disabled=False,
    button_style='', # 'success', 'info', 'warning', 'danger' or ''
    tooltip='Click me',
    icon='check' # (FontAwesome names without the `fa-` prefix)
)
button
```

therefore, the following code will also work:

```py
import ipywidgets as ipyw

ipyw.Button(
    description = 'Button',
    icon = 'bullhorn',
)
```